# Rectangle Zoom-in: Accounting for proportions and distances between them

Tags: geometry

Let's say I have n rectangles: each with their own height and width, and each with their own coordinate on a plane.

I can scale the width and height of the rectangles by let's say...S. How do I adjust the distances between them to make a proper zoom-in effect (so they don't overlap)? I want the distances between the objects all scaled by S ideally.

Comment: I don't see how you can adjust the distances between rectangles while not changing their center points.

Comment: Oh, I want you to change the center points. I'll change the wording.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you know the coordinates of the corners of each rectangle. Then all you need to do is multiply each coordinate by $S$ to get the "zoomed" (i.e. scaled) rectangles.

For instance, if $S = 1/2$ and the upper left hand corner of the first rectangle is $(-1, -3)$, then the new upper left hand corner of that same rectangle will be $(-1/2, -3/2)$. Do this to all the coordinates of all the corners and you'll be done.

Of course, you don't need to know the coordinates of every corner in order to determine each rectangle. All you need is the coordinate of one corner of each rectangle (say the upper left-hand corner) and the width and height of each rectangle. If this is the data you're keeping, then simply multiply all quantities by $S$ as above. For instance, if $S = 2/5$ and you have a rectangle with upper left-hand corner $(1, 4)$, width $3$, and height $7$, then its new upper left-hand corner will be $(2/5, 8/5)$, its new width will be $6/5$, and its new height will be $14/5$.

If you wish to keep one point stationary (say the center of one of the rectangles) it is convenient to choose coordinates so that this point is $(0, 0)$.

Comment: I guess by choosing $S < 1$ this is actually zooming out, but the principle and process are the same for zooming in.

Answer (score 0):

You first choose a center of your zooming, let's say where your mouse is. Let this center be (x0, y0). Now let the old coordinate of a rectangle be (x, y). The new is then (S* (x-x0) +x0)  ,  S*(y-y0)+y0).